# Set a null date in a jtable

Tags: java, date, jtable

I want to be able to select no date in a cell with date in a JTable but I can't. When the date picker is open, I need to select a date or the previous date remains. How can I do this? I tried to follow the code but JTable does everything inside.

[this is how my data editor looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7aua.jpg)

Thank you

Comment: you forgot to include the code)

Comment: The code is a classic code. I just extend AbstractTableModel and override getColumnType. The problem is when I use the table ... the code doesn't have any problem

Comment: it is rather hard to help you without knowing your "classic" code.

Comment: I add a photo how my editor looks but it has no option to select no date. How can I set up a editor that allow me to select null date

Answer (score 1):

Apply to your JTable method:

```
jotTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
```

Your method should look typically:

```
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return ((Object[]) cache.elementAt(row))[col];
      }
```

Use DefaultTableCellRenderer
Here is an example.

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer LPRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
            @Override
            public void setValue(Object value) {
                int cellValue = (value instanceof Number) ? ((Number) value).intValue() + 1 : 1;
                String disp = (new StringBuilder()).append(" ").append(new Integer(cellValue)).append(" ").toString();
                setText(value != null ? disp : "null");//diplay text "null" if null value
            }
            public void setBackground(Color c) {
                super.setBackground(new Color(213, 213, 213));
            }
        };
```

LP is one of columns (TableColumn)
LP.setCellRenderer(LPRenderer);

maybe you telling what if I populate JTable with some data from DB? if you catch `java.lang.NullPointerException` you can do this :
for example

```
try
{
   data_set = SQL_query.getData();
   table.addData(data_set);
}
catch (NullPointerException nullPointer)
{
   table.addData(NULL_DATA_SET);  // in case of NullPointerException
}
```